# Can't convert NoneType to Float in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, floating-point, cs50

I'm working on Finance for cs50, and in this part of my project, I want to calculate the total profit of the user.

```
total_funds = db.execute("SELECT extra_funds FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])

funds_cash = total_funds[0]["extra_funds"]

profits = total - funds_cash
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/cs50/pset8/finance/application.py", line 69, in index
    profits = total - funds_cash
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I've already tried saying:
`funds_cash = float(total_funds[0]["extra_funds"])`
But this didn't work. Hopefully, you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Try printing `total_funds[0]` and `funds_cash`, and tell me what you get. The problem may be that `total_funds` isn't an array or that `total_funds[0]` doesn't have the `extra_funds` key.

Comment: Does the field contain a `null` in the database?

Comment: Hey! This helped. Printing the values made me notice that the value was None. So I set it to NOT NULL and defaulted it to 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

NoneType = None .."nothing" if you will. That means that soemthing in the equation is yielding no value hence it cannot be converted to float (or anything for that matter). My guess would be the total_funds query doesn't return anything. Try running a print on that and you might get further.